# Excel multiple percentage increases/decreases of multiple varied numbers

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, data-visualization

I'm attempting to find a way to see a useful view of number fluctuations across a number set with varied variables. All of the variables are from a single source, but are their own subcategories and are from a month of activity. I tried using percent increase/decrease from one day to the next, but seeing "1" increase to "4" resulting in a 300% doesn't help me much.

I have some sample data to better explain. I just can't figure out a good way in excel to identify where in this data is a significant increase because of how varied the numbers are.[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNXQS.png)

Comment: Definition of "significant" is the problem here (statistically significant? practically significant?).  For example an increase of 1 to 4 may or may not be significant depending on the measure (eg "number of heads" vs "beans")  A simple start might be to apply "heatmap" conditional formatting on a per-row basis and look for outliers.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to the stack as both a casual researcher and asking questions. I'll post a link to a file that can be manipulated. Mind you, I'm not asking folks to do my work FOR me, but to help me learn how to be able to do it myself so I can use the skills going forward.

[Google Sheets for easy copying](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sxjmwUT6R9wQkK5-kFXS_6Rr5otoIDB9R4A0WmRCJVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pnuts ::hands up:: fair enough, I'm not familiar with the SE culture so I extend my apologies and will happily accept the guide to the destination. I see the CF work here and I see the value for it.  What were the metrics used to identify the color selections?